# Left shift but replace the shifted bits with ones

Tags: python

In Python the `<<` operator does the following:

Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying x by 2**y.

I want to have another version where it fills `1` on the new bits. Is there a built in function for this, if not how do I write it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `x = (x << y) | ((1 << y) - 1)` what you're looking for?

First, we shift x left y bits:

```
x = 21
y = 2
bin(x) == 10101 (in binary)
x << y == 1010100
```

Then, the number ((1 << y) - 1) gives us a number with only the y lowest bits set to 1,
e.g.

```
1 << 2 == 100
(1 << 2) - 1 == 011
```

Finally, we `or` them to get `1010100 | 11 == 1010111`.

Comment: Hi could you explain this code piece in more details please?

Comment: `(1 << y) - 1 = 2**y -1` contains `y` ones in binary representation `|` means bitwise or.

Comment: @a6623 Updated post

Answer (score 6):

There's no such function built in, or, for that matter, available in any extension library I know of.

It's pretty easy to do yourself, though. Say the int is `n` and you want to shift it left by `s` bits.

First flip all the bits of `n` (change all 0 bits to 1, and all 1 bits to 0). Then shift left by `s`. That adds `s` 0 bits on the right. Then flip the bits again. The new trailing 0 bits are changed to 1 bits, and the original bits of n are restored.

```
>>> n = 5
>>> bin(n)
'0b101'
>>> ~(~n << 6)
383
>>> bin(_)
'0b101111111'
```